# Trying to build an Kivy OSX package .app with buildozer but getting errors

Tags: macos, kivy, buildozer

Followed the instructions for buildozer on the kivy doc site: https://kivy.org/docs/guide/packaging-osx.html#using-buildozer.
I've tried with both Python 3 and 2 and still getting the same errors... Any help?

Error here:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "package_app.py", line 234, in <module>
    main(arguments)
  File "package_app.py", line 223, in main
    compile_app(appname)
  File "package_app.py", line 157, in compile_app
    shell=True)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 540, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['myapp.app/Contents/Resources/script -OO -m compileall myapp.app']' returned non-zero exit status 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/buildozer", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('buildozer==0.32', 'console_scripts', 'buildozer')()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/buildozer/scripts/client.py", line 13, in main
    Buildozer().run_command(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/buildozer/__init__.py", line 1020, in run_command
    self.target.run_commands(args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/buildozer/targets/osx.py", line 234, in run_commands
    func(args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/buildozer/targets/osx.py", line 250, in cmd_debug
    self.buildozer.build()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/buildozer/__init__.py", line 210, in build
    self.target.build_package()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/buildozer/targets/osx.py", line 155, in build_package
    check_output(cmd, cwd=cwd)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 573, in check_output
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd, output=output)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['python', 'package_app.py', '/Users/myuser/Desktop/myapp/.buildozer/osx/app', '--appname=myapp', '--bundlename=My App', '--bundleid=org.test', '--bundleversion=0.1', '--displayname=My App']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind. Figured it out.
Installed pyinstaller in python and kivy. Then edited buildozer file osx.py line 163 to: binpath = join(dirname(abspath(self.buildozer.specfilename)), '.buildozer')

Comment: Could you add some detail to this answer?